# Collecting in map using Collector.toMap

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am not able to get my head around a simple problem. 
I have a map of type X and it needs to be transformed into map of type Y

```
mapOfTypeX.entrySet().stream().map(e-> transform(e)).collect(Collector.toMap(....));
```

The transform function takes the entry set and gives back Map of type Y e.g `Map<key,SomeClassObjectAsValue>`

```
public Map<key,SomeClassObjectAsValue> transform(Map.Entry<String,Person> entry){}
```

I am not sure what to pass to the Collector.ToMap function. The existing code is an imperative code and it passes the map of type Y to the transform function and doing `map.putall`

Comment: Why not do a `putAll` only? What's wrong in that approach.

Comment: putAll returns void , so essentially it is a side effect and i don't want that. Also in future i want to move from stream to parallel streams and then i feel that side effects like these can cause problem. So i want to transform the map first and then collect the results in the target map.

Comment: The question is not really clear on the aspect that why would you want to transform a `Map.Entry` to a `Map` and what is your current imperative style of writing this?

Comment: In your return type of `Map<key,SomeClassObjectAsValue>`, what is `key`? What is `SomeClassObjectAsValue`?

Comment: The key is instance member of class SomeClassObjectAsValue and this member itself is a class with two members one is string other is date.
SomeClassObjectAsValue {
 Key k;
}
Key {
String prop1;
LocalDate prop2

--hash code and equals method implemented
}

Comment: Naman-> Its a functional requirement where in i have to iterate over one map and transform that into another map. There are some validations that we have to do on the key of source map, hence i am using entry instead of key and values seperately.

Comment: @whysoseriousson the question is more why not transforming from entrySet to entrySet?

Comment: May be i didnt specified this in the question . But for each entry key i have to create new hash map and the transform function is different.Also in the final hash map there will no role of the key of the original hash map, it is just use to choose the transform function.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to use the [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) function instead of using `toMap` wrapper.

```
mapOfTypeX.entrySet().stream()
          .map(e-> transform(e))
          .collect(HashMap::new, HashMap::putAll, HashMap::putAll);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [flatMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) of streams and combine all entries from all maps recieved from transform method as:

```
Map<key,SomeClassObjectAsValue> newMap = 
    mapOfTypeX.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> transform(e).entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors
            .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,(oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
```